# XPath tokenize() method not recognized by msxml3.dll

Tags: xpath, attributes, tokenize, msxml

I'm attempting to use the tokenize method in a SelectNodes(" ") call, to filter some things out.

I have something along the lines of:

```
<nodes>
    <node colors="RED,BLUE,YELLOW"/>
</nodes>
```

And my xpath is as such:

```
nodes/node[not(empty(tokenize("GREEN,YELLOW,PURPLE", ",") intersect tokenize(@colors, ",")))]
```

Simply, I've got two comma delimited list, one as an attribute, and one as a "filter" for the attributes.  I want to select all nodes where `@colors` contains, somewhere, one of the words inside of `"GREEN,YELLOW,PURPLE"`.

I thought I had the solution for it with that XPath, but it seems either:
A: I did something wrong, or
B: The version of XML DOM document I am using does not support `tokenize()`

The XPath above, in a SelectNodes( ) call will throw up an error message, saying msxml3.dll: Unknown method.", then pointing to the `tokenize()` method.

I tried doing setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath"), but that did not seem to solve the issue either.

Is there any way for me to perform an equivalent XPath selection, without resorting to a bunch of `and contains(@colors, "GREEN") and contains(@colors, "YELLOW")...`?

Comment: `empty`, `tokenize`, and `intersect` are all XPath 2.0 features, and MSXML only provides XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

As JLRishe says, msxml does not support XPath 2.0.

Depending on the environment that you are in there is probably third-party software you can use that supports either XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 (which is a superset of XPath 2.0).

Microsoft's XML software is getting very dated and there has been little new development for 10 years now. It's time to consider alternatives.